# Declaring MySQL PK as only Unique Key

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, primary-key

Can creating a UNIQUE index on an Id as shown in the create table below be enough to make the id a Primary Key? TO be more specific, can you say that the table below has a Primary Key?

```
test` (
`id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`role` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
`resources_name` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
`access_name` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
`allowed` int(3) NOT NULL,
UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`),
UNIQUE KEY `roles_name` (`role`,`resources_name`,`access_name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=32 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

What query can you use to prove that this has or has no PK?

Comment: A PRIMARY KEY is one defined as a PRIMARY KEY.  UNIQUE KEYS are candidates, but are not PRIMARY KEYs by definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logically speaking if a relational table has at least one candidate key enforced in it (minimally unique and non-nullable) then de facto it has a "primary" key. There is no absolute need to single out any one key using a special "primary" label because in principle all keys are equal (historically the term "primary key" used to be used for any and all candidate keys and not just one key per table).

There is a constraint in SQL called a PRIMARY KEY constraint. Logically speaking, the SQL PRIMARY KEY isn't much more than syntactical sugar because the NOT NULL UNIQUE syntax achieves essentially the same thing. Technically the PRIMARY KEY constraint doesn't have to refer to the same thing as the relational concept of a "primary key" but clearly if you are going to designate any one key as primary and if you feel you need a syntactical way of indicating that choice then the PRIMARY KEY constraint is the generally recognised way to do it.

So perhaps the best answer is "it depends". It depends to a large extent on your motivation for defining a primary key in the first place. If you intend to single out one key to developers and users of the database then maybe the NOT NULL UNIQUE syntax won't achieve that for you. If you don't find the need to do that using SQL syntax then maybe NOT NULL UNIQUE is just as good a way to define your keys as the PRIMARY KEY constraint is.

Answer (score 0):

This is either too long or too short for a comment:  No.

A primary key and a unique key -- although similar -- are not the same.  So, no your table does not have a primary key.  The biggest functional difference is that primary keys cannot be `NULL` whereas unique keys can be.

Primary keys are also typically clustered (if the underlying storage engine supports clustered indexes).  This means that the data is actually physically stored on the page in the order of the primary key.  Unique keys are just another index with the characteristic of having no repeated values.

EDIT:

Interesting.  `SHOW COLUMNS` [documents](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-columns.html) this behavior:

> A UNIQUE index may be displayed as PRI if it cannot contain NULL
>   values and there is no PRIMARY KEY in the table.

I wasn't aware of this.

Comment: But when i run the SQL command "SHOW COLUMNS FROM test" it actually shows the Id as PRI?

Comment: @TheGeorgia . . . Perhaps MySQL treats a non-nullable unique key as a primary key.  I'm not aware that it does, but your experience suggests that it is possible.  (I would always declare that column to be a primary key directly.)

Comment: But since it is auto_increment, it means it cannot contain nulls anyway. It is guaranteed to always have a value.

Comment: Also, what does it mean to declare AUTO_INCREMENT=32, what does that do as shown in the table above?

Comment: @TheGeorgia . . . That sets the initial value for the column.

Comment: Unique keys don't permit nulls. A candidate key by definition allows only unique values and not nulls. If a column is nullable then it's wrong to call it a "key" or part of a key. If a set of columns *doesn't* permit nulls and is subject to a uniqueness constraint then there *is* a key. The tautology "unique key" is actually doubly incorrect when applied to nullable "UNIQUE" constraints in SQL because such constraints don't even enforce uniqueness (according to the SQL standard). MySQL compounds the problems of terminology even more because it uses KEY as a synonym for index. Go figure!

Comment: @sqlvogel . . . I don't know what you mean.  MySQL definitely allows `NULL` values in unique keys (http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cfba6).  Unique indexes allow `NULL` values ( http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-index.html) and the MySQL documentation does not distinguish between "unique index" and "unique key".  Perhaps in some world outside the ANSI SQL standard "unique key" has the meaning you want it to have, but the methods used in MySQL are consistent both with the standard and with most other databases.

Comment: MySQL is not standard SQL. What MySQL calls a key is demonstrably not a key because it doesn't even have to be unique. The weird "KEY" syntax used by MySQL certainly is not something defined anywhere in ISO/ANSI SQL. The fact that the authors of MySQL got it wrong doesn't alter the definition of what a key is and always has been for at least the last 45 years.